# Counting the amount of users or executions of an application.

Tags: vb.net, variables, publish

I made a program that gets the data from the clipboard and saves it in a string variable. Then it looks for specific words in that string and generates several URLs. Afterwards it open the browser and shows each URL in an own tab. 
Some of my friends already use this program frequently and I want to have some statistics about how often. I simple counter variable would be enough but I need to get access to it. 
I came up with two options that could work:

1. I could send an email to a specific adress every time my app is executed. Then I can track the amount of uses by manually or automaticly counting the amount of emails in the postbox. I think this would be a Vers dirty solution.
2. I could create and publish a website containing a counter. This counter could be refreshed by my application. This solution is a bit better I think but a lot more work for just one single counter.

Do you have better ideas to solve my problem or is one of mine already a good one?

Thank you in advace!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Measurement Protocol Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). This provides you statistics of usage your application compared with Google Analytics. You can see even a geo statistic, version distribution, crash reports. It is [easy to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api) it from .net. It is just about [requesting http request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) to google.

Comment: Thank you! Easy to use is of course relativ. I am having some problems using the protocol. I can't find example codes for vb. I made a metric but have no idea how to get and set its value with vb...

Comment: There are some questions on this topics on Stackoverflow. Or ask a question, it should be separated.